# Binary expressions in C

Tags: c, binary-operators

```
int i = -1, j = 1, k, l;
k = !i && j;
l = !i || j;
printf("%d %d", i, j);  // prints "-1 1"
```

Please explain to me how this works so that I can understand it properly.

Comment: What is your present understanding of what this code does?

Comment: The answer is just a good-introductory-book-on-C away.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i=-1,j=1,k,l;
k=!i&&j;
l=!i||j;
printf("%d %d",i,j);
```

nor *l* nor *k* are printed, *i* and *j* are unchanged, so for the *printf* point of view it is the same as

```
int i=-1,j=1;
printf("%d %d",i,j);
```

or

```
printf("-1 1");
```

---

If you are anyway interested by the value of *k* and *l* :

- `!i&&j` is `(!i)&&j`, *i* values -1 so `!i` values 0 (false for a logical operator), so `!i&&j` is valuing false, so *k* values 0
- `!i||j` is `(!i)||j`, *i* values -1 so `!i` values 0, *j* is 1 (true for a logical operator), so `!i||j` is `false||true` valuing true, so *l* values 1 or any non null value

Comment: Nit: As a lead programmer I would have rejected these two lines of code as incompetent (notwithstanding that they do nothing). Now, I know the precedence order of the operators, but If I look at this code, I cannot determine whether the writer knew the rules. In cases like this, parentheses are your friend.

Comment: I think that the day we expect programmers to put parentheses around the unary negation operator to clarify evaluation precedence is the day we admit that we expect future programmers know nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=-1,j=1,k,l;

k=!i&&j;  // The value of K is not used; the value does not matter
l=!i||j;  // The value of L is not used, the value does not matter

printf("%d %d",i,j); // i is -1, j is 1, the output is "-1 1"
```

The output is:

```
-1 1
```

The logic is very simple.